# Chi-square test of independence variables grouping?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, survey

I'm having trouble solving something regarding the variables.

Let's say that I want to assess the dependence between `Var1` and `Var2`, and between `Var1` and `Var3`. My data is going to be taken from a questionnaire. I want to do something like this:

```
Questionnaire Design (n= >100*):
Var1: Q1y/n, Q2y/n, Q3y/n, Q4y/n.... (yes/no)
Var2: Q5sd-sa, Q6sd-sa, Q7sd-sa... (5-point likert-scale; strongly disagree-strongly agree)
Var3: Q8sd-sa, Q9sd-sa, Q10sd-sa... (5-point likert-scale; strongly disagree-strongly agree)
```

Now how do I prove my hypothesis? Can I get it by the grouping of the variables? Or should I change each variable to 1 question? In my mind the end hypothesis is going to be Q1 and Q5, Q2 and Q5, etc... but I want it to be Var1(Q1-Q3) and Var2(Q5-Q7).

Or should I do it with a different test?

P.S.: total question and sample number provided are arbitrary.